# How to retrieve email based on time in Google api using c#?

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

How to retrieve email based on time in Google api using c#? 
Can we pass date time to query string for getting the latest email?
While working around this one i am able to find pas the date only.
Is there any way to get the latest mail based on time?

Comment: Actually I want the mail based on the Time, not with the Date. Query parameter is like after:2015/6/28 12:55:00 PM before:2015/7/1 02:30:00 Am. Thanx in advance                                                                                      I want to read the emails based on particular time interval.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can achieve this by passing in a query parameter along with Get Message List call of Gmail API like below:

```
  List<Message> result = new List<Message>();
  UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
  request.Q = query;//This is where you put in your data query

  do
  {
      try
      {
          ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
          result.AddRange(response.Messages);
          request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
      }
  } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));
```

Query parameter is the same as you pass in your mailbox search box. e.g. after:2015/6/28 before:2015/7/1

Afterwards, fetch individual message details by calling Get with message ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I want the mail based on the Time, not with the Date.              Query parameter is like after:2015/6/28 12:55:00 PM before:2015/7/1 02:30:00 Am. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Yes, right. In essence, you can pass in the same query parameter as you would in Gmail search box.

Answer (score 3):

Furhan's answer is great. I would just like to add, that if you want to search for mails more specifically than 2015/6/28, you can supply e.g. `after:<TIME_IN_SECONDS_SINCE_EPOCH>`

Let's say you wanted mail after:2015/6/28 12:55:00 and before:2015/7/1 02:30:00, your would write:

```
after:1435496100 before:1435710600
```